# Implementing view switching with return values

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

So, I'm building an iOS4 app that has a login screen and has to switch to a different screen after that.

I implemented the login screen in its own view controller and the other screen also has its own view controller. How would I go about switching screens while still preserving the data I need from the Login Screen?

I've looked at the View Controller Programming guide on the apple developer website, but I can't quite seem to grasp what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to switch views.  Navigation controller as suggested by Eugene is one way.  To Preserving data, you can use instant variables or private variables.  There is an excellent iOS development tutorial on [this site.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)

Added example of instant variables:

Interface header .h file

```
@interface MyUIViewController : UIViewController

{
   NSString *myString;  //instant variable  

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
```

Implementation .m file

```
@implementation MyUIViewController
@synthesize myString;

//somewhere in your code 
-(void)testMethod
{
    self.myString = @"whatever value";
}
```

Comment: instant variables? Would you mind showing me a small code example of what you mean?

Comment: I should also have mentioned that you can also use private variables as well.  If you remove this line from above code NSString *myString; then myString becomes private variable.  The difference is that with instant var you can access it from other classes that have an instance of its  viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't necessarily use your instance variable storage. I had to transfer cookies along, so what I did is implement a `NSHTTPCookieStorage` object in the places where I needed it and used the shared storage for the application. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Build your application as Navigation based app. Use UINavigationController instead of UIViewController with your UIViewController as it's root. Then when redirecting user simply do this in your view controller:

```
//create your custom view controller on which you want to redirect user
MyCustomViewController *viewController = ...;

//push view controller and animate the transition
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Anyways dig into `UINavigationController` and how it works.